# Failure to install hsev on Windows 10 via `stack install hsdev`

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hsdev

I get this error when running `stack install hsdev` outside and inside of a project:

```
λ stack install hsdev
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-5.11 from implicit global project's config file: C:\Users\atc\AppData\Roaming\stack\global-project\stack.yaml
While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package hformat in known packages

--  Failure when adding dependencies:
      hformat: needed (>=0.1), stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.1.0.0)
      simple-log: needed (>=0.3.4), stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.3.4)
      text-region: needed (>=0.1), stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 0.1.0.0)
    needed for package hsdev-0.1.8.2

--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package simple-log in known packages

--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package text-region in known packages

Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in C:\Users\atc\AppData\Roaming\stack\global-project\stack.yaml
- hformat-0.1.0.0
- simple-log-0.3.4
- text-region-0.1.0.0
```

I have run `stack update` prior to attempting this. I want to install `hsdev` so I can use [SublimeHaskell](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell).

`stack solver` gives:

```
λ stack solver
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-5.11 from implicit global project's config file: C:\Users\atc\AppData\Roaming\stack\global-project\stack.yaml
Using configuration file: AppData\Roaming\stack\global-project\stack.yaml
The following packages are missing from the config:

<snip long list of references to directories in AppData\Local\Temp\stack14228\>

No cabal packages found in AppData\Roaming\stack\global-project\stack.yaml. Please add at least one directory containing a .cabal file. You can also use 'stack init' to automatically generate the config file.
```

Relevant stack info:

```
λ stack --version
Version 1.0.4, Git revision cf18703b1392a96a5a4896a560309e501af63260 (3220 commits) x86_6
```

Comment: have you tried the **recommended action**? (just edit the file and add those - then retry)

Comment: Question updated with `stack solver` output

Comment: see [here](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#adding-dependencies) please (look for the `acme-missle` example - your problem seems to be exactly that) - also did you add the `extra-deps` for your update or not?

Comment: I did a `cabal install hsdev` and it installed ok. Will try with stack now.

Comment: Please include your stack.yaml, and if you are using cabal better use sandboxes otherwise you can run into problems in the near (or far) future

Comment: I came here looking for why `cabal install hsdev` wouldn't install on my machine, which is a different issue, but I figured it out, so I thought I would mention the solution here. The error was "ExitFailure 1", scrolling up, there was a "permission denied". The solution was to kill ghc, ghci, and hsdev via Task Manager, and then try again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got `hsdev` installed on my windows machine by the following steps.

1. Run `stack unpack hsdev` to download the source of hsdev to the working directory.
2. Move into the directory, run `stack init --solver` to create a proper `stack.yaml` build config.
3. Run `stack install` to build and copy the executables to your local bin directory. If stack reports an error about a missing LICENSE file create an empty `LICENSE` file under `./tests/test-package`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!